# Partial Views vs. Json (or both)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I use ASP.NET MVC with jQuery and have a lot of Ajax requests to my controllers.

Use Partial Views (usercontrols) to build the intial view when a page is loaded. Then if I need to append/replace data based on my Ajax request I build HTML from the Json response.

This approach gives me full control, ie. I can get extra information back from my controller if something went wrong, and then show an error message based on that.

However, recently I've been really annoyed with all the extra work that goes into maintaining HTML structure both in my partial views and the part that generates HTML from Json.

I like to make a jQuery ajax request and then have the controller return PartialView("mypartialview") and then just use jQuery to replace to HTML in the view.

However, this way I cannot attach extra data from the controller - it's either whatever the partial view gives me - or nothing. At least that's my current take on it.

If some validation goes wrong at some point in my controller action I don't want to return the HTML of the partial view.

So how do you go about handling this issue?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 20):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string) stackoverflow anwser I have just set out to do the same thing.

First create an extension method for the controller class.

```
public static string RenderViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
         var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
         controller.ViewData.Model = model;
         var viewCxt = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, writer);
         viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
         return writer.ToString();
     }
}
```

Then return the json in the controllers action method.

```
return Json(new {
  Html = this.RenderViewToString("MyView", model),
    SomeExtraData = data
});
```

Your ajax requests will now receive json with the html contained in it.  Still experimenting with this approach over returning plain Html fragments.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT** Updated to work with razor

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to take advantage of the `Content-Type` returned by each respective result.  We are using this to send back error information, and there's already JS in place to display messages, so we get either the partial view we want, or control information for error reporting etc.

For reference, a partial view returns `text/html` and a JSON response should return `application/json`.

As usual, the fun part is on the javascript side, and the JQuery `ajax()` does not disappoint here!

In your controller, just return either `PartialView()` or `Json(model,)` as appropriate; we are using it in `try/catch` format.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    try {
        var model = getYourModel();
        return PartialView("Edit", model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        var mi = new MessageInfo(MessageType.Error, String.Format("Edit failed: {0}", ex.Message), true);
        return Json(mi, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

On the JS side, we are using the following function.  Note that you need to re-establish any JQuery events you hooked in `$(document).ready()` from the initial page-level GET, so we have a callback parameter.

```
function getPartialView(action, controller, model, divId, callback) {
    var url = "/" + controller + "/" + action + "/";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: model,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var ct = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            var mx = ct.match("text\/html");
            if (mx != null) {
                $(divId).html(data);
                if (callback) {
                    callback($(divId));
                }
            }
            else {
                addMessage(data.type, data.title, data.text, data.sticky);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            addMessage(3, "\"" + url + "\": Failed", textStatus + ": " + errorThrown, false);
        }
    });
}
```

The only tricky bit is checking the `Content-Type` header in the response, and behaving accordingly.  Please note we are "cheating" by assuming JSON if it wasn't HTML.  We are calling our pre-existing `addMessage()` function, do whatever you need!

And finally, here is a sample Anchor element with `onclick` targeting `getPartialView()` above.

```
<a href="#" onclick="getPartialView('Action', 'Controller', model, '#partialviewdivid', function(dvx) { connectJqueryEvents(dvx); })">Cancel</a>
```

**Works Great...**

Except for form submits via `Ajax.BeginForm()` where the JSON payload is treated mistakenly as HTML due to insufficient validation of `Content-Type`.  The result is your `div` gets some JSON added to it, which basically does not render as HTML.  The `AjaxOptions.OnSuccess` callback does execute, but it's too late for your DOM at that point!

There is a simple solution, but unfortunately it requires a small *repair* to `jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js` because the `asyncOnSuccess()` function was short-sighted as written.

```
function asyncOnSuccess(element, data, contentType) {
  var mode;

  if (contentType.indexOf("application/x-javascript") !== -1) {
    return;
  }
  if (contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
    return;
  }
...snip...
}
```

In the OOTB version, the second `if` statement is missing; adding it is the fix necessary to keep it from slamming your JSON payload into the DOM.

With this fix in place, the JSON payload passes into your `AjaxOptions.OnSuccess` Javascript, and you can proceed as necessary.

**Yes You Can Get Both**

Hopefully you know since you are sending Json, you could send back any kind of model, and let the Javascript sort it out; `hasOwnProperty()` comes in handy there.  So obviously you can send back some view HTML via already-mentioned `RenderViewToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could return the rendered html as a string - this could alternately be an html string containing an error message to display?

Comment: Indeed, that is just what a PartialView response is. And though you don't quite spell it out, this is the solution: Have your AJAX methods return a rendered PartialView using the same user control you used to render that portion of the page initially. You do this by writing return PartialView(model) instead of return Json(model).

Comment: Craig, that is what I do now. My problem is that I want to return both Html and Json - or to put otherwise: I want the resulting html that is returned from return PartialView and then wrap in Json, so that I can send along other data as well.

Kind of like this guy:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168791/returning-a-rentered-html-partial-in-a-json-property-in-asp-net-mvc

I guess the above would work, but I'd like to know how others handle this.

Comment: You can (easily) return the same model as either a partial view (HTML fragment) or JSON. Build the model, then call whichever method you need. But don't write JavaScript which duplicates your partial view from a JSON serialization of the same model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way as well, Put this Inside your controller.

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```