# ASP.Net MVC - Need to send other data along with Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, partial-views

I need to send some other data, ideally wrapped in a JSON object, down to the client. As well as that however I need to send a Partial view. Now I can only think of two ways:

1. Send JSON object and then make another call to load contents of partial view into div.
2. Send HTML for Partial View as a property of the JSON object and then load it into div.

How would I go about doing the second option? Is there a command to render partial views into a string? Or is the first approach better?

Cheers,
Damien

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471066/partial-views-vs-json-or-both/5502426#5502426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a command to render partial
>   views into a string

No direct way as I know of.  But it's possible with some mocking.  I use [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) here, but any mocking framework would do.

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
response.Setup(res => res.Output).Returns(writer);

var oldContext = ControllerContext.HttpContext;
ControllerContext.HttpContext = context.Object;

var partialView = PartialView("TagCloud", tags);
partialView.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
var resultHtml = writer.ToString();

ControllerContext.HttpContext = oldContext;
```