# ASP.NET MVC - Returning a PartialView to Ajax along with another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am writing a single page ajax app with ASP.NET MVC - making heavy use of jQuery.  I do something similar to the following throughout the app:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/GetSomePartialView/",
    data: someArguments,
    success: function (viewHTML) { 
        $("#someDiv").html(viewHTML); 
    },
    error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
});
```

Controller C#:

```
public ActionResult GetSomePartialView(SomeArgumentModel someArguments)
{
    
    return PartialView("_CaseManager");
}
```

This works great.  The `viewHTML` (in the ajax `success` function) is returned as a string and I can shove it on the page no problem.

Now what I would like to do is to return not only the PartialView HTML string, but also some sort of status indicator.  This is a permissions thing - for instance, if someone tries to get to a portion of they app they don't have permission to, I want to return a different PartialView than they asked for and also display a message in a popup window telling them why they got an View different from what they asked for.

So - to do this, I would like to do the following:

Controller C#:

```
public ActionResult GetSomePartialView(SomeArgumentModel someArguments)
{
    ReturnArgs r = new ReturnArgs();
    
    bool isAllowed = CheckPermissions(); 
    
    if (isAllowed) 
    {
        r.Status = 400; //good status ... proceed normally
        r.View = PartialView("_CaseManager");
    }
    else
    {
        r.Status = 300; //not good ... display permissions pop up
        r.View = PartialView("_DefaultView");
    }
    
    return Json(r);
}

public class ReturnArgs
{
    public ReturnArgs()
    {
    }

    public int Status { get; set; }
    public PartialViewResult View { get; set; }
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/GetSomePartialView/",
    data: someArguments,
    success: function (jsReturnArgs) { 
        
        if (jsReturnArgs.Status === 300) { //300 is an arbitrary value I just made up right now
            showPopup("You do not have access to that.");
        }
    
        $("#someDiv").html(jsReturnArgs.View); //the HTML I returned from the controller
    },
    error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
});
```

This **SORTA** works right now.  I get a good object in JavaScript (what I am expecting to see), however I cannot see how to get at the full HTML string of the `jsReturnArgs.View` property.

I am really just looking for the same string that would be returned if I were just returning the `PartialView` by itself.

(As I mentioned at the beginning, this is a single page app - so I can't just redirect them to another View).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So - using the following posts I got this working:

[Partial Views vs. Json (or both)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471066/partial-views-vs-json-or-both)

[Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

They both lay it out nicely, then I changed my code to the following:

C#:

```
public ActionResult GetSomePartialView(SomeArgumentModel someArguments)
{
    ReturnArgs r = new ReturnArgs();

    bool isAllowed = CheckPermissions(); 

    if (isAllowed) 
    {
        r.Status = 400; //good status ... proceed normally
        r.ViewString = this.RenderViewToString("_CaseManager");
    }
    else
    {
        r.Status = 300; //not good ... display permissions pop up
        r.ViewString = this.RenderViewToString("_DefaultView");
    }

    return Json(r);
}

public class ReturnArgs
{
    public ReturnArgs()
    {
    }

    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string ViewString { get; set; }
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/GetSomePartialView/",
    data: someArguments,
    success: function (jsReturnArgs) { 

        if (jsReturnArgs.Status === 300) { //300 is an arbitrary value I just made up right now
            showPopup("You do not have access to that.");
        }

        $("#someDiv").html(jsReturnArgs.ViewString); //the HTML I returned from the controller
    },
    error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

one way to skip having to return a json with multiple parameters and your html encoded as json is to send an HTML always but you send a hidden field that has the status set in it or something like that..

```
success: function(data)
{
  if(data.find("#ajax-status").val()==="success")
  {
    $("#someDiv").html(data);
  }
  else
  {
    showPopup("You do not have access to that.");
  }
}
```

I wouldnt recommend this appraoch I would have two partial views one for the normal view and the other for the error/unauthorized case..

Comment: I appreciate the input!  I was trying to avoid something like that if I could.