# Using Ajax to render MVC View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, view, asp.net-mvc-4

The task I am trying to accomplish basically involves me using AJAX to call an MVC view, and render the content of the view into my main content div. I understand that as I won't be doing a full page reload, just a refresh on the content I need, I will need to be altering the URL string to account for whichever controller and action I am attempting to call, to get the required view. I havent done a lot of Ajax as of yet, as I am only a junior developer, however I am very interested in learning how to achieve things such as this, and anything that follows.

I am using C# as my primary language, and can use either mvc3 or mvc4, whether or not that makes much difference, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax.ActionLink for this...

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click here", "OtherAction", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "MyDiv" })

<div id="MyDiv">

</div>
```

**Action**

```
Public ActionResult OtherAction(long id)
{
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hello!";
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Hello!</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Button:
@supplierQuoteId is from the model via Razor.

```
<a id="@supplierQuoteId" class="t-button" style="float: right; margin: 3px; padding: 2px; line-height: 0;" 
    onclick="ajaxEditSupplierQuote(this.id)">
    <span class="t-icon t-edit">Edit</span>
</a>
```

JavaScript:
If $.ajax is complete, I open a Telerik Window and there is a .Content - div with the id="supplierquote-dialog-contet" which is then filled with the returned PartialView from the Controller, otherwise, i set .html(" ") . Empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function ajaxEditSupplierQuote(id) {
        var strUrl = "/SupplierQuote/Edit" + "/" + id.toString();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: strUrl,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data) {
                    $('#supplierquote-dialog-content').html(" "); // error check
                }
                else {
                    $('#supplierquote-dialog-content').html(data);
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
                var window = $("#SupplierQuoteDialog").data("tWindow");
                window.center().open();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

SupplierQuoteController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        SupplierQuoteEntity supplierQuote = _supplierQuoteRepository.GetById(id);
        return PartialView("Edit", supplierQuote);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question, very similar you yours.

[ASP.NET MVC - Returning a PartialView to Ajax along with another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589787/asp-net-mvc-returning-a-partialview-to-ajax-along-with-another-object)

Stealing some code from there you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetSomePartialView(SomeArgumentModel someArguments)
{
    ReturnArgs r = new ReturnArgs();

    r.ViewString = this.RenderViewToString("SomeView");

    return Json(r);
}

public class ReturnArgs
{
    public ReturnArgs()
    {
    }

    public string ViewString { get; set; }
}
```

Then in view:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/GetSomePartialView/",
    data: someArguments,
    success: function (jsReturnArgs) { 

    $("#someDiv").html(jsReturnArgs.ViewString); //the HTML I returned from the controller
    },
    error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
});
```