# Ajax do not pass data to method using GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a method which Is accesed using `Get`

```
[HttpGet]
[AdminAuthorization]
public ActionResult MakeReservation(ReservationModel m)
{

    return PartialView(m);
}
```

here Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/DeviceUsage/MakeReservation",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: Ids }),
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Dodanie  nie powiodło się  Jeden lub wiecej numerów seryjnych nie są unikalne " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ProperModal.modal-body').html(data);
            $("#Modal").modal('show');
            //if (data === "sukces") {

        }
    });
```

If I change method description and ajax type to `POST` function works. How should I modify this code to make it work wiht `GET` calls?

Comment: Not an answer, but **stop** stringifying the `data`, jQuery accepts an object directly!

Comment: make the rest call GET first...

Comment: @Alexander no. Received data `ReservationModel m` is null when using `GET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in your controller. For more information you could read [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

And I think it is good practise to return Json (not PartialView) in your action (for ajax). If you want to return PartialView, you could use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10590386/2392330)

Comment: Thanks. But as I read the `AllowGet` is placed in return. But as you can see my method doesn't return `JSON`

Comment: Oh, okey. Let's see about Json vs PartialView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471066/partial-views-vs-json-or-both

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explictly tell the `HttpGet`, By Default, it takes it as `HttpGet`, but if you put `HttpPost` attribute, then it does not work on Get Requests.

Same is the case for Jquery ajax, if you don't tell it, its get or post request, it by default makes a get request to server

Answer (score 0):

Remove contentType and dataType: 'json' (this indicates you are returning json, but your code returns a partial view). And Remove JSON.stringify as jQuery accept your JS object directly. Haven't tested it, but it should work.